# The best way to operate output data models to build custom JSON?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have some nested models with nested models.

best way to operate output data models to build custom JSON?

Now It is uncomfortable to iterate each model, add each others to separated array and after join by key.

Comment: The package [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) is made specifically for this.

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: How so, what doesn't work?

Comment: It does not work for nested relations, also I need unique structure JSON

Comment: It very much does work with nested relations. That one of the biggest advantages of using Fractal! What exactly do you mean "unique structure JSON"? Because I'm pretty sure it will do that for you too if you use the transformers correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, you can add `protected $hidden` or `protected $visible` arrays as properties on the model class which will automatically hide or only make certain columns visible in JSON responses.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Additionally, you can use mutators to modify certain attributes when converting your models to JSON.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#introduction

You can also add additional attributes not in your database to your JSON responses when converting a model to JSON.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Example

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['is_admin'];

    public function getIsAdminAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['admin'] == 'yes';
    }
}
```